# The object with the type "xxx" cannot be converted to type "yyy"

Tags: c#, java, .net, soap, service

I'm having problems calling a method from a service. The error only occurs in .NET, Java seems to work fine. Most of the methods from the service work with .NET, so far 2 of them have thrown Exceptions. The service is open if you want to try and reproduce: http://radar.zhaw.ch/services/AirTrafficWebService.wsdl

**Exception**

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  Message=Das Objekt mit dem Typ "AirTrafficWcfWrapper.ServiceReference1.Airplane[]" kann nicht in den Typ "AirTrafficWcfWrapper.ServiceReference1.AirplaneTrackingPoint[]" konvertiert werden.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       bei System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
       bei System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
       bei System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalSetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean doVisibilityCheck, Boolean doCheckConsistency)
       bei System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalSetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean doVisibilityCheck)
       bei System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture)
       bei System.Reflection.FieldInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value)
       bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
       bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
       bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       bei AirTrafficWcfWrapper.ServiceReference1.AirTrafficWebService.getAirplaneTrackingPoints(getAirplaneTrackingPointsRequest request)
       bei AirTrafficWcfWrapper.ServiceReference1.AirTrafficWebServiceClient.AirTrafficWcfWrapper.ServiceReference1.AirTrafficWebService.getAirplaneTrackingPoints(getAirplaneTrackingPointsRequest request) in D:\Projekte\C#\WP7\Airtraffic\Tests\SilverlightDesktop\AirTrafficWcfWrapper\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:Zeile 1234.
  InnerException:
```

It is thrown in a generated Reference.cs file like this:

```
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    AirTrafficWcfWrapper.ServiceReference1.getAirplaneTrackingPointsResponse AirTrafficWcfWrapper.ServiceReference1.AirTrafficWebService.getAirplaneTrackingPoints(AirTrafficWcfWrapper.ServiceReference1.getAirplaneTrackingPointsRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.getAirplaneTrackingPoints(request); //<--HERE
    }
```

**.NET call:**

```
AirplaneTrackingPoint[] tps = _airTrafficService.getAirplaneTrackingPoints(icao, 0, 0, false);
```

**Java call:**

```
List<AirplaneTrackingPoint> tps = service.getAirplaneTrackingPoints(icao, 0, 0, false).getItem();
```

**EDIT:**

The response seems to be made up out of a list containing a list of both an Airplane object and the single objects that AirplaneTrackingPoint is made of (e.g. [0] Airplane, [1] Latitude, [2] Longitude, [3] Bearing etc.). So it seems that .NET is taking the first element out of the element of the list and using that as a return value. Java seems to ignore the first element of the list in the list and instead makes an object out of the rest of the list.

Can anybody explain this behaviout?

Comment: Maybe you changed something in the service definitions and forgot to update your service reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you changed the service and forgot to update your service reference? Maybe earlier you returned a list of `Airplane` objects and some time you changed it to return your own new data structure. If you right-click on the service reference in your .NET project you can choose to update it, at which point the code that does everything for you (in Reference.cs) is recreated.

UPDATE: I can confirm that it's not working out of the box in VS2010.

I tried to run the client in .NET 4 and .NET 3.5. The first time I got some strange fault exception from the server with an SQL query string inside, now I'm only getting the cast error over and over. I followed standard VS2010 procedures to add a service reference, so there's either the service to blame or the WSDL doesn't work with svcutil (also a likely issue).

I got the following error when I changed the service reference to always generate message contracts and use these:

> {"The top XML element 'return' from namespace '' references distinct types System.String and AirplaneTrackingTest.AirTraffic.Airplane[]. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types."}

I would contact the service provider and ask for proper test parameters to their methods and if they have a reference client implementation in C#.

Comment: I've done that a few times, and the organization which offers the service has verified that it hasn't been changed in about 3 years.

Comment: I've updated my answer, unfortunately I could only confirm that it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for the help and effort, I'm working on getting the XML directly now and then parsing it. Seems to work so far, but it is a nuisance. Added new info I found too.

Comment: Ok, found the Answer: .NET 2.0 Compability mode: Add a Web Reference, not a Service Reference. Gonna mark yours as answer anyway because you helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you will need to add in a cast, presuming that the two types are compatible. You are returning an AirplaneTrackingPoints from the service and storing them as Airplanes, this sounds a little odd to me.

Your Java method calls getItem which is not present in your c# code could that be it?

Comment: I'm calling the service, it is closed. I've tried casting, using var and using dynamic. The second thing is a design difference, .NET directly returns what you need to do with getItem() in Java.

Comment: Well I dont know how java is working here but I would say change your list to be of type Airplane. That should get it compiling but then you might need to loop though converting them to be of the correct type. You might be able to use adapter pattern to get it to behave like you want then but without know what the code is like its hard to sa

Comment: If I try to accept a list of Airplane then the program won't compile. I've verified through Java that the service does return AirplaneTrackingPoint[], not Airplane[].